# How do I make the photo fix the box

Tags: html, css

Basically I got a framework for this slideshow which I am currently using however when I put the pictures on it, the picture is enlarged but I want the entire picture to fit the box. if you could help me to do this then this would be great.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

as u can see the picture is enlarged and some of it is missing

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class='slider'>
  <div class='slide1'></div>
  <div class='slide2'></div>
  <div class='slide3'></div>
  <div class='slide4'></div>
  <div class='slide5'></div>
  <div class='slide6'></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.slider {
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;

}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5.slide6,.slide7,.slide8,.slide9,.slide10 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}



/*default is not 20s its usually 8 IM TRYING TO CHANGE THE LENGTH OF TIME IN WHICH IT STAYS ON THE SCREEN */
.slide1 {
  background: url(../img/Slideshow/img1.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 20s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
  background: url(../img/Slideshow/img2.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade2 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 20s infinite;
}
.slide3 {
    background: url(../img/Slideshow/img3.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 20s infinite;
}
.slide4 {
    background: url(../img/Slideshow/img4.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 20s infinite;
}
.slide5 {
    background: url(../img/Slideshow/img5.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 20s infinite;
}
.slide6 {
    background: url(../img/Slideshow/img6.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 20s infinite;
}
.slide7 {
    background: url(../img/Slideshow/img7.jpg)no-repeat center;
      background-size: cover;
    animation:fade3 20s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 20s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 1}
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

some other css u might need

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;

    /*Background Image */

    background-image: url(../img/Background-Blurred.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The image is cropped because you used `background-size: cover;`, if you use `background-size: contain;` it won't be cropped, you can also use specific dimentions like `100%` if you don't mind changing the aspect ratio.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

try to replace background-size: cover; 
with  
object-fit: fill; 
if you don't care about breaking aspect ratio